# Is there an efficient approach in machine learning when I have the confidence (uncertainty) values for the input features?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, feature-engineering

Could you give me some comments?

I'm looking for a better approach when I have confidence (uncertainty) values for each input feature.

For example, let's say each class has 3 features.

```
f1,value = 0.003
f2,value = 0.005
f3,value = 0.007
```

And they have their own confidence value [0-1 range]. (It means how reliable the feature is.)

```
f1,conf = 0.2 (not reliable)
f2,conf = 0.8 (reliable feature!)
f3,conf = 0.6 (so-so)
```

Actually, the low confidence value is because of noise and other interferences.

I'm using conventional neural network and put these values in series.

ex) [f1value, f1conf, f2value, f2conf, f3value, f3conf]

But is there any better approach to use the confidence values?

For example, is there any way to put 'confidence values of input features' to learning network?

----added

Actually, I have the confidence values. You can think of these values as signal quality.

Comment: This might be addressed with a weighted analysis.  Weights are things like the reciprocal of the variance so if you can convert confidence into the variance scale you might be set.  Weighted analysis is standard in multiple regression, so should be available in some ML algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I think that including confidence values as features doesn't make sense from a ML perspective. The algorithms themselves are designed in a way to perform feature selection. However, if you want to compute confidence values for each feature (meaning how informative the feature is) you can use a statistical test to compute that. An example for such test is Pearson's chi-squared test. When it comes to the implementation you can have a look at the [Sklearn's SelectKBest](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest.htmlhttps://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest.html). If you pass the [chi-squared](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.chi2.html) score function (or any other feature selection metric) you can return the feature importance scores.